# Could not Found the main Class in Java while i'm running

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

I have a java swing code In that There are 5 classes, the Main Class refer other four classes, here i added some jar also, i give the following cmd for compiling,

```
C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\FinalAttempt\install\lib>javac WriteHelper.java JavaDemo.j
ava DataBaseHelper.java FileEncryption.java SendEmail.java -cp dnsns.jar;dsn.jar
;imap.jar;javaws.jar;jce.jar;jsse.jar;jxl-2.6.jar;localedata.jar;mail.jar;mailap
i.jar;pop3.jar;rt.jar;smtp.jar;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar;sunjce_provider.jar;sunmscapi
.jar;sunpkcs11.jar;tools.jar JavaSamp.java
```

Here JavaSamp holding mainclass the other classes are WriteHelper,JavaDemo,DataBaseHelper,fileEncription and SendEmail classes, when i Complied using above cmd it Compiled Successfully, When i run this class i having the following Exception

```
C:\Users\FSSD\Desktop\FinalAttempt\install\lib>java WriteHelper.java JavaDemo.ja
va DataBaseHelper.java FileEncryption.java SendEmail.java -cp dnsns.jar;dsn.jar;
imap.jar;javaws.jar;jce.jar;jsse.jar;jxl-2.6.jar;localedata.jar;mail.jar;mailapi
.jar;pop3.jar;rt.jar;smtp.jar;sqlitejdbc-v056.jar;sunjce_provider.jar;sunmscapi.
jar;sunpkcs11.jar;tools.jar JavaSamp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WriteHelper/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WriteHelper.java
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: WriteHelper.java.  Program will exit.
```

How do i overcome it, thanks in advance...

Comment: While running java file don't use `.java` extension. Also you will required to specify only the name of the main class in java command not all java file, but the -cp part is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You don't run a Java class by telling it about *source* code. You tell it which class to run. For example:

```
java -cp .;dnsns.jar;...[... as before ...] com.foo.JavaSamp
```

That's assuming a class called `JavaSamp` in a package of `com.foo`. Note that when you compile, you should probably use something like `-d .` to tell it to put the class files into a folder structure rooted in the current directory, based on the package name within the source file.

Comment: Hi Jon, i have only 6 (JavaSamp,JavaDemp,DataBaseWriteHelper,WriteHelper,FileEncryption,SendEmail)classes with in it one is My Mainclass, while i comple it have the following Names of classes... {DataBaseHelper.classes,FileEncryption.class,JavaDemo.class,JavaSamp.class,SendEmail.class,WriteHelper.class, JavaSamp$1.class,JavaSamp$2.class,JavaSamp$3.class,JavaSamp$4.class,JavaSamp$Myemail$1.classJavaSamp$Myemail$2.class...etc } why it should be happened

Comment: @Ben Ten: (Sorry to interrupt between you and jon) Because you have some anonymous classes in your java file. (In JavaSamp.java)

Comment: @BEN Ten: The `JavaSamp$1` etc classes are likely to be anonymous inner classes. You can ignore them. You just need to find out which class you want to launch - the one containing the `main` method.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/format/CellFormat
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jxl.format.CellFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)

Comment: @BEN Ten: Well where is that class meant to be, and have you included the relevant jar file or directory in your classpath?

Comment: @BEN: better add the error messages (and the command you used) to your question (it has an edit link). It looks like it needs the jar file.

Comment: @BenDennison: Any reason for removing the acceptance of this answer? Has something changed?

Answer (score 0):

To run a java file, you specify which **class file** (ends with a `.class` extension but you don't specify the extension) and the rest of the classes and libraries (with a `.jar` extension) are provided in the classpath.

e.g.

```
java WriteHelper -classpath "<directory_where_class_file_exists>;mail.jar/localedata.jar;
```

To compile the file, use `javac` instead. What you did is you told java to look for `java` in `WriteHelper` directory (or package).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `java WriteHelper.java`  you are telling Java to look for a class called "java" in the "WriteHelper" package.  It isn't there, and that is what the exception is telling you when it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **WriteHelper/java**

Run the class as `java WriteHelper`.  The `java` command expects a class name ... not a class file name.

---

There are other problems with the way that you are compiling and running code.

- The `-cp` option and its value must appear before the names of the Java source files (for `javac`) and the name of the Java class (for `java`).
- The `java` command expects ONE class name, not lots of class names.  You need to figure out which class is the one with the `public static void main(String[] args)` method and use that one (only) as the `java` class argument.  (I would guess, that if you have a class called `Main` that that has the `main` entry point method.)
- This will only work if the classes are all declared in the default class.  If the source code starts with a `package` declaration, you need to organize the classes in a directory tree whose components mirror the class packages; see @Jon Skeet's answer.

Finally, you would be well advised to read the manual pages for `java` and `javac` carefully, along with the linked page that talks about how the classpath works.  Once you understand them, this stuff won't seem like black magic anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the classes generated in the first step to the class path in the second step.